# MVC4 : Sending child Partial view values to controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

First of all I must say this I am new to MVC4 and developing this app and learning MVC4 simultaneously :).

In this app,
Below is the **parent view** where 3 partial views are rendered also there is one button:

```
[code]
 <td id="track">@Html.Partial("_Track",Model)</td><br>
<td id="tech">
 <div id="Technologies"> @Html.Partial("_Technology",Model)
</div></td></tr> 
..
[some code]
..

<td class="subtopic">
 <div class="subtopiclist" id="subque">@Html.Partial("_Subtopics",Model)</div><br>
 <input type="Submit" value="Fetch Interview Questions" name="Fetch" id="Fetch" />
           </td>
```

Partial View1 (it contains dropdownlist) :

```
@model MvcApplication3.Models.CommonWrapper

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SelectTrack", "Home", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "Technologies" }))
{ 
    @Html.DropDownListFor(
            m=>m.SelectedTrackId,
            new SelectList(Model.track, "TrackId", "TrackName"),
           string.Empty
        )
}
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#SelectedTrackId').change(function () {
        $(this).parents('form').submit();
    });
</script>
```

Parital View2 (it contains dropdownlist):

```
@model MvcApplication3.Models.CommonWrapper
@if (Model.tech != null && Model.tech.Count() > 0)
{
    using (Ajax.BeginForm("SelectTechnology", "Home", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "subque" }))
    { 
     @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SelectedTrackId)
     @Html.DropDownListFor(
            m => m.SelectedTechId,
            new SelectList(Model.tech, "TechId", "TechName"),
            string.Empty
            )
    }
}

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('change', '#SelectedTechId', function () {
        $(this).parents('form').submit();
    });

</script>
```

Partial view 3 (it contains multiple checkboxes):

```
@if (Model.subtopic != null && Model.subtopic.Count() > 0)
{
<table>
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.subtopic.Count; i++)
{
 <tr><td>
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.subtopic[i].IsSelected, new { id = "subTopic_" + i })
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.subtopic[i].SubtopicName)
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.subtopic[i].SubtopicName)
     <td>
     </tr>   
}
</table>

}
```

Now In parent view, I want to fetch the values from these three partial views.Also, I need to send these fetched values to controller.
How to do this ? can anybody please help me on this.
Thanks in advance

Added controller code :

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SelectTrack(int? selectedTrackId)
        {
            CommonWrapper wrapper = new CommonWrapper();
            wrapper.tech = new List<TechModel>();

            if (selectedTrackId.HasValue)
            {
                wrapper.tech = (from s in CommonWrapper.GetTechnology()
                                where s.TrackId == selectedTrackId
                                orderby s.TechName
                                select s).ToList();
            }

            return PartialView("_Technology", wrapper);

        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SelectTechnology(int? selectedTechId)
        {
            CommonWrapper wrapper = new CommonWrapper();
            wrapper.subtopic = new List<SubtopicsModel>();

            if (selectedTechId.HasValue)
            {
                wrapper.subtopic = (from s in CommonWrapper.GetSubtopics()
                                           where s.TechId == selectedTechId
                                           orderby s.SubtopicName
                                           select s).ToList();
            }

            return PartialView("_Subtopics", wrapper);

        }
```

Comment: None of this is magic (just somewhat obscured). Start by simply viewing the output HTML of you page and you will see how the form and the inputs are structured (just like a normal single form with lots of fields). **One problem is you are nesting forms on the partial views when you probably want a single form in the parent.** Most of it will bind to the received Model `as-is` as you are using indexing correctly for the arrays. Please show your controller code.

Comment: Hi TrueBlueAussie I have added controller code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the ajax forms to simply using jquery to post to a desired controller action. This then separates your partial views from requiring an update target.

You can apply this method for each of your drop down lists calling a different controller action.

Remove your Ajax.BeginForm's and the corresponding jquery code and replace each with the below.

**Parent View**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function ()
    {
        $("#SelectedTrackId").change(function ()
        {
            var selectedValue = $(this).val();
            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "post",
                data: selectedValue,
                url: url,
                success: function (data)
                {
                    // data contains your partial view
                    $("#some-container-id").html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help David. I tried using first approach and it is working for me :)

Answer (score -1):

I'd put together a ViewModel and put this in the `[HttpPost]` Controller Action

Hope this helps

Christian

Comment: It would be very helpful, if you will share some dummy code snippet.